# Issues regarding Templates in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am developing an app for User Registration and Login.I have made the Registration form and now i am now wants to make a login page,for that reason i have made a login.html file and now i want it to be placed in the templates.
Thus I create a directory and placed it in that directory **home/html/templates/registration/login.html**

The Template_dir=() in **settings.py** file is as:

```
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        '/home/html/templates',
    )
```

The view file as

```
from django.template import  loader
from registration.models import Registration
from django.http import HttpResponse

def login(request):
    t = loader.get_template('registration/login.html')
    return HttpResponse()
```

But when I am trying to run this file as **localhost:8000/registration/login.html** I am getting the 404 error  **Page not found**

the url given in **url.py** file is as:

```
url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.login'),
```

Comment: You are returning an empty HttpResponse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not serve html files itself. Templates must be rendered and returned as HttpResponse on a view.py.

So try:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

And `localhost:8000/registration/` will return you a login page.

See docs for more info about [shortcuts functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#module-django.shortcuts) and [template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-django-template-language-for-python-programmers)

Comment: **I did like that but it doesn't work**

`from django.template import  loader
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from registration.models import Registration
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    def login(request):
        t = loader.get_template('registration/login.html')
        #return HttpResponse("Hello, login here")
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')`

Comment: Hi again ,sorry for inconvience but I am totally new to django so now i am getting the error of view login does not return an HTTPRequest object, the details are in the below link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157932/http-request-object-does-noy-respond]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `404` because you are trying to access `localhost:8000/registration/login.html` while you defined url as `url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.login'),`.

String rather regex in first part in definition in `urls.py` should match the URL that you access from browser.

In your case you should access `localhost:8000/registration/`.

Also, you should be returning proper http response rather than empty `HttpResponse`.