# HTTP Request Object does not respond

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am making a login form in Django.
When I am click on login submit button , It gives an error of

**ValueError at /registration/
The view registration.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object.**

The view file is

```
from django.template import  loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from registration.models import Registration
from django.http import HttpResponse
def login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    if user is not None:
      if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        # success
        return HttpResponseRedirect('sucess')
      else:
        # disabled account
        return direct_to_template(request, 'inactive_account.html')
    else:
      # invalid login
      return direct_to_template(request, 'invalid_login.html')

def logout(request):
  logout(request)
  return direct_to_template(request, 'logged_out.html')
```

and login.html file is

```
<h3>Login</h3>
<form action="/login/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label for="username">Username:--</label><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" /><br>
<label for="password">Password:-- </label><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" />
<p><input type="submit" value="Login →"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Two things I see - What happens if the request is GET? You don't return anything, and `sucess` is misspelled.

Comment: [direct_to_template returns an HttpResponse too](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/views/generic/simple.py#L14). @BurhanKhalid is correct.

Comment: @yeah Burhan is right but normally direct_to_template used from urls.py m i rit ?

Answer (score 1):

Your login view will return a HttpResponse for a POST request only (on form submit). When you address your browser to login page, it makes a GET request, which is not handled in your view

I`ll recomend you to read more about user athentication: [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

And as mentioned, use `render` or `render_to_response` functions `from django.shortcuts`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `direct_to_template` you may want to use `render_to_response` which renders a given template and returns HttpResponse.

Refer [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response). Note; you will have to import it using `from django.shortcuts import render_to_response`

Comment: after suggestion and modification now i am getting **MultiValueDictKeyError at /registration/

"Key 'user_name' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"**

Answer (score 0):

Why not you are using `render_to_response`  ?

The answer of your question is you are not returning the `Httpresponse` object

If your login is successful then only you will be redirect to success .

Try this

```
 return render_to_response(your_template_name, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Don't forget to import context_instance like

```
from django.template import RequestContext
```

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError at /registration/ "Key 'user_name' not found in <QueryDict: {}>  because you are not passing the user_name in your dict however your current problem is solved better to ask a new question

Comment: remove value = "" from input fields then try

Comment: you should have to refer doc first anyway send me ur mail id i am sending you script

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15894/discussion-between-user1614526-and-neeraj)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15897/discussion-between-neeraj-and-user1614526)